# Grand Total not changed

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout-page

[image]I modified tax for the shipping by using observer "**sales_quote_address_totals_after**", which make changes in the Order Summary. But the Grand Total not getting changed, and when I make order, changed grand total is showing on admin.

When I see the grand total in network, it shows the changed grand total. Attached an screen-shot below

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue myself. Make a sales.xml and use an model to do this

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful.  - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/114873)

Comment: @KeyurShah You should be able to self answer a question. I do think @RishabhRkRai you should explain a bit more. What would be the contents of the `sales.xml`? How would that make it work?

Comment: Yes, I apologise for the mistake @7ochem

Comment: @Rishabh Can you please share your code.